# vuejs namespace getters undefined error

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am having difficulties testing namespaced getters although it works I am not able to test it successfully.

```
getContextMenuListSelectedState: function (menu) {
  return this.$store.getters['appContext/getContextMenuListSelectedState'](menu)
}

<view-switcher @switchView="setCurrentView" />

setCurrentView: function (obj) {
...
let maintSelected = this.getContextMenuListSelectedState('docsmaint').label === 'maint'
...
}

is throwing an error in test:
'[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "switchView": "TypeError: this.$store.getters**.appContext/getContextMenuListSelectedState** is not a function"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was quite misleading. I finally was able to stub it with a fake. After refactoring it as provided above.

```
 function fakeGetter (menu) {
      return store.state.appContext.contextMenusLists[menu].filter((item) => {
        return item.selected
      })
    }

getContextMenuListSelectedStateSpy = sinon.stub(omsLayout.methods, 'getContextMenuListSelectedState').callsFake(fakeGetter)
```